# merge two arrays in ascending order

Tags: arrays, sorting, merge

i wanted to put two sorted arrays into one array in ascending order, but i don't what i did wrong.

it won't put them in order, just combine the two arrays together.

```
int [] merged = new int[count1 + count2];
int merg1 = 0, merg2 = 0, index = 0;

while (merg1 < count1 && merg2 < count2) {
    if (ary1[merg1] <= ary2[merg2]) {
        merged[index++] = ary1[merg1++];
    }
    else {           
        merged[index++] = ary2[merg2++];
    }

    while (merg1 < count1) {
        merged[index++] = ary1[merg1++];
    }

    while (merg2 < count2) {
        merged[index++] = ary2[merg2++];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        System.out.print(merged[i] + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the last two while loops for? You may not need them. It seems that you sort the first two numbers then the while loops copy the first array then the second without sorting them.

Comment: without the while loops it'll print out messy integers :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you share how the results look for the following?

```
arry1 = [1,2,6,7]
arry2 = [2,3,4,8]
```

I agree with Paradox, without the two additional while loops, your logic above should be enough. ex:

```
while (merg1 < count1 && merg2 < count2) {
    if (ary1[merg1] <= ary2[merg2]) {
        merged[index++] = ary1[merg1++];
    }
    else {           
        merged[index++] = ary2[merg2++];
    }
}
```

Comment: without the while loops it'll print out "1 2 2 3 4 6 7" it doesn't include the 8

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the error come from the

```
while (merg1 < count1 && merg2 < count2) {
...
}
```

It terminates when one of the numbers goes past its limit. After the while loop, I would add another loop that adds the rest of the remaining array to the merged array.

Answer (score 0):

can you just use the Array utilities? For example:

```
    int[] array1 = {1,2,6,7};
    int[] array2 = {2,3,4,8};
    int[] mergedarray = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, mergedarray, 0, array1.length);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, mergedarray, array1.length, array2.length);
    Arrays.sort(mergedarray);
```

That should give you the results your are looking for.